# redux state change doesnt trigger re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, render

[this is my state interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFBlw.png)

```
case UPDATE_CONVERSATION_ACTION:
  var list = state.messageList ? state.messageList.length > 0 ? state.messageList : [] : [];
  if(list.length > 0) {
    let val = state.messageList.findIndex(e=>e.postId === action.payload[0])
    if(val !== -1) {
      var messageItem = {} as MessageListItem

      var item = state.messageList[val];
      var messages = item.messages;
      messages.push(action.payload[1]);
      messageItem.messages = messages
      messageItem.postId = action.payload[0];
      list[val] = messageItem
    }else {
      list.push({postId: action.payload[0],messages : [action.payload[1]]})
    }


  }
  else {
    list.push({postId: action.payload[0],messages : [action.payload[1]]})
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    messages: [...state.messages, action.payload],
    messageList :list
  };
```

---

```
<FlatList

    data={this.props.messagesList  ? this.props.messagesList.length > 0  ? this.props.messagesList.find(e=> e.postId === this.state.postId)?.messages ?? [] : [] : []}renderItem={({ item }) => (
        this.renderItems(item)
    )}
    // extraData={selected}
  />
```

now i listen data from socket i got data dispatch it and update list there is no problem for it bu react didnt render my flatlist component but its changed. only if react render component i press any key in input, react render it message

i did make changes like

```
var existMessageList = state.messageList.findIndex(e => e.postId === action.payload[0]);

  return {
    ...state,
    messageList : existMessageList !== -1 ? state.messageList.map((val,i)=> val.postId === action.payload[0] ? {...val, messages : state.messageList[i].messages.concat(action.payload[1])} : val) : 
    [...state.messageList,{postId : action.payload[0],messages : [action.payload[1]]}]
  };
```

it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating the existing state with all of the `.push()` and `list[val] =` lines.  Please don't do that.

See [the Redux docs page on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) and the post [The Complete Guide to Immutability in React and Redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/) for information on how to correctly write immutable updates.

I'd strongly recommend using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  It has a `configureStore` API that will catch mutations by default, and the `createSlice` API actually lets you write "mutating" logic that is safely turned into correct immutable updates.

Comment: but i declare a var `list` in the first line in state case i did changes with push or list with new variable, does it affect existing state ://

Comment: `var list` is pointing to the existing `state.messageList`, which is the existing array. As the Redux docs page explains, that's a very common mistake to make.

Comment: i did make changes like